# Отключить вывод исключение YII2

Tags: php, yii2, yii

Не могу найти как отключить вывод исключений. Подскажите как это сделать? Имею ввиду, что не хотелось бы что бы это увидел кто то кроме меня.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну тут вопрос в том, что будут видеть другие пользователи вместо исключения? Белый экран? Или какую-то заглушку? Если переключить ENV в PROD кажется и так не будут эксепшены показываться. Вообще все зависит от того как построенно ваше приложение. Либо переопределить компонент **Response** либо посмотрите на **actionError** у дефолтного контроллера

Comment: @Ninazu да нужно в прод переключить, нигде не могу найти как это сделать. Конкретно в данном случае я хочу что бы эксепшен остался только в логах сервера а пользователя кинуло на 404.

Comment: Вроде бы так. В корне проекта файл `yii`. Изменяете `defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'prod');`

Comment: @robertobadjo изменил, не помогло :(

Comment: @robertobadjo - в **yii.php** это если человеку через консоль нужно поменять окружение. Если для веба то в **index.php**
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic/blob/master/web/index.php